# Issue with not like Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that reads like this

```
 Select distinct student_id,student_name, student_id+'-'+student_name from student_table
where student_id='1' and (upper(student_name) not like 'testing%'
 or upper(student_name) not like '%testing')
    group by student_id, student_name
    order by student_name asc
```

The Student id 1 contains a field Testing data.
If is use 'like' or 'not like' in both cases the record is returned.Essentially not like does not appear to work.Any solutions to this?

Sample data:-

```
student_id  student_name
1           testing data
```

Comment: why are you converting it to UPPER and then using a lower case string literal?

Comment: @MartinSmith I had done that to remove the case senstivity.But even without it,it does not work.

Comment: if your server uses a case-sensitive collation, then neither `testing%` nor `%testing` nor `TESTING%` nor `%TESTING` will be `like 'Testing'`, which is what you said the data was at first. Now you say it is `'testing data'`. Which is it?

Comment: @underscore_d testing data is the value in the field

Comment: To "remove the case sensitivity", if you are even on a case sensitive collation, comparing an upper case string to a lower case string clearly isn't going to work

Comment: @MartinSmith I've removed the upper and it still doesn't work

Comment: *Why* a `DISTINCT` **and** a `GROUP BY` and why a `GROUP BY` when there's no aggregation? Do you understand what either of those operators do?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to construct a value that would match the condition `not like 'testing%' or not like '%testing'`, because

1. You are using an `or` condition, where I think you probably meant to use an `and` condition, and
2. Even if you were using an `and` condition, many possible values would meet both predicates. For example, a varchar value of 'abc' is `not like 'testing%'`, because `'testing%'` only matches values that start with the letters "testing", and it is also `not like '%testing'`, because `'%testing'` only matches values that end with the letters "testing".

Also, unless you are using a case sensitive collation (which is not a default), the `upper()` method will have no impact. If you are using a case sensitive collation, then for any input value to `upper()`, the result will be uppercase, which means it will not be filtered out by either predicate, because those are both lower case. That is to say, every value will be both `not like 'testing%'`, and `not like '%testing'`

Edit: Thanks for your additional comment, your requirement is clearer. You don't want the value to start or end with "testing", and you want to be sure of a case insensitive comparison. In that case the condition you want is:

```
where   student_id = '1'
        and upper(student_name) not like '%TESTING'
        and upper(student_name) not like 'TESTING%'
```

As an aside, it is a bit odd to have a "student_id" column whose name seems to indicate it contains numeric values, but then to compare the column to a character version of the numeric value. Are you sure you don't just want `where student_id = 1` instead of `where student_id = '1'`? Without seeing the schema of your table it's hard to say.

Comment: I want to remove any data that starts with starting or ends with testing.So I believe OR is the right choice here

Comment: In that case your condition should be something like `where not (student_name like 'testing%' or student name like '%testing')`, But you still have a puzzling use of `upper()`'

Comment: @underscore_d no I want to find ones that does not contain testing

Comment: then write that... these are not the same thing. anyway, if you wanted 'starts or ends with', then using `or` was wrong, and so this answer is correct. if you wanted 'contains', then they told you how to do that too.

Comment: So, `not(a or b)` is the same as `not a and not b`. It is not the same as `not a or not b`. And as @underscore_d was pointing out, "contains" is different from "starts with or ends with". For example, the value `abcdef` "contains" `cd`, but neither starts with nor ends with `cd`. So I'm confused again as to which one you actually need.

Comment: working example that removes the record with `not (a or b)`. feel free to use this query to illustrate your answer; you already covered the logic behind it, so i'd just be copying you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/09904/6

Comment: @allmhuran in the example you have outlined it abcdef is okay.I just don't want it to end with or start with cd(irrespective of case)

Comment: @user13597631 From your other comment, I see you are trying to "remove case sensitivity". Assuming you do have a case sensitive collation here, then to "remove case sensitivity" you must convert *both* sides of the comparison to either upper or lower case, or force a case insensitive collation during the comparsion with the [collate clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarificaiton, I have adjusted my answer to include the where clause that I believe you are looking for. Note that I have spelled out "TESTING" in upper case explicitly rather than doing `upper('%testing')`.